# Помогите оптимизировать PHP код (древовидные комменты, рекурсии)

Tags: php, рекурсия, комментарии

Здравствуйте.

Слепил код вывода древовидных комментариев из примеров в интернете. Работает как надо, но кто подскажет как оптимизировать?

**Алгоритм:**

1) Запросом узнаю кол-во родительских (parent=0) комментариев к текущей статье, устанавливаю переменные $start и $end (зависят от параметра GET 'page') и $total (лимит комментариев на 1 страницу).

2) Делаю запрос на выборку всех комментариев к этой статье (родительские+дочерние), кидаю их в массив all_comments.

3) Выполняю функцию-рекурсию buildTree, передаю ей массив all_comments, результат сохраняю в $newarr, т.е получаю иерархию со всеми родительскими и дочерними комментариями такого вида:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [comment_id] => 1
            [content] => Содержимое ответа
            [parent] => 0
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [comment_id] => 2
                            [content] => Ответ на комментарий с comment_id=1
                            [parent] => 1
                            [children] => 
                        )
                )
        )
```

4) В цикле for ($i=$start; $i < $end; $i++) прохожусь по элементам newarr, например лимит 5 комментариев на страницу, всего родительских 12 штук (сколько дочерних без разницы), тогда для page=1 $i будет от 0 до 4, для page=2 от 5 до 9 и для page=3 от 10 до 11. В теле цикла выполняю функцию-рекурсию getCommentsTemplate($newarr[$i]), которая рисует каждый комментарий (включая дочерние).

В итоге код работает правильно, но  мне не нравится столько массивов и две функции-рекурсии. Есть вариант оптимизировать?

**Часть кода, которую хочу улучшить**

```
function getCommentsTemplate($comment) { // функция выводит комментарии в читаемом виде
    $html = '';
     ob_start(); 
     echo '<li>';
     echo $comment['content'];
if(!empty($comment['children'])) { // если существует вложенный массив children
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($comment['children'] as $value) echo getCommentsTemplate($value); //рекурсия
    echo '</ul>';
}
    echo '</li>';   
    $html .= ob_get_clean();
    return $html;
}

function buildTree($itemList, $parentId) { //функция, которая строит древовидные комментарии, принимает массив и ID родителя
  $result = array();
  foreach ($itemList as $item) {
    if ($item['parent'] == $parentId) { // если значение ключа parent соответствует ID комментария-родителя
      $newItem = $item;
      $newItem['children'] = buildTree($itemList, $newItem['comment_id']); // рекурсия, заносим вложенный масив в ключ children
      $result[] = $newItem;
    }
  }
  if (count($result) > 0) return $result;
  return null;
}

$all_comments = array();

$result = $db->prepare('SELECT comment_id, content, parent FROM comments WHERE category=:category_id ORDER BY date DESC');
$result -> bindParam(':category_id', $category_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$result->execute();

if ($result->rowCount() > 0) { // если есть комментарии
$result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
while($row = $result->fetch()) $all_comments[] = $row; // создаю массив со всеми комментами к статье

$newarr = buildTree($all_comments, 0); // строим массив с иерархией всех комментариев к этой статье, включая дочерние

echo '<ul>';
    for ($i=$start; $i < $end; $i++) echo getCommentsTemplate($newarr[$i]); //рисуем комментарии
echo '</ul>';   
}
```

Comment: Может вам стоит кешировать структуру комментариев и загружать из базы только содержимое отображаемых на странице.

Comment: Может быть, но мозгов не хватит переделать, на текущий код потратил часа 4)